# Switch statement. Working with default case

Tags: php

I have 3 days of week: Mon, Wed, Fri.
For every one of them I have a number. I need to make a switch that will throw me that number BUT if today is Saturday, I won't have anything declared in my switch statement so what I need there is the number from Friday.

```
<?php
$x = date('d');
class week {
    const Mon1 = 7;
    const Wen1 = 2;
    const Fri1 = 4;

    const Mon2 = 14;
    const Wen2 = 9;
    const Fri2 = 11;

    const Mon3 = 21;
    const Wen3 = 16;
    const Fri3 = 18;

    const Mon4 = 28;
    const Wen4 = 23;
    const Fri4 = 25;

    const Wen5 = 30;
}

switch ($x){
case week::Fri1:
    echo "Results 11111"; break;
case week::Fri2:
    echo "Results 22222"; break;

default:

break;
}; ?>
```

Today is saturday.
I need the default to throw the Fri2, as the Fri2 case is the last `valid` case.

On Sunday, what I need would be the results from Friday.

On Thursday I will need the results from last Wednesday and so on.

Is there any way to do it using a switch statement?
If not, what would you use to do this?

Comment: Store the past value and if on Saturday you don't update it, the last value will be that of Friday

Comment: Why are you building a class here?  Why not a simple array?

Comment: @ChrisWillard It seems reasonable to me - the closest PHP comes to what other languages would call an "enumeration".

Comment: An array would be a bit more messy I guess. Is easier for me just to call Mon1, Fri2 etc

Comment: @RyanJ, sorry, I don't think I understand how do yo say to store the last valid value from this switch. Please give me just a hint :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
If i understand you correctly, you need as default value the last workday of the week befor today.

maybe you can use something like:

```
switch(date('w')) {
    case 0:
    case 6:
        $foo = week::Fri2;
        break;
    default:
        $foo = 'your logic'; 
        break;
}
```

---

you can use:

```
switch ($x){
    case week::Fri1:
        echo "Results 11111"; 
        break;
    case week::Fri2:
    default:
        echo "Results 22222"; 
        break;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is an option. Fri1 and Fri 2 are just 2 examples. I will have mon1, wed1, fri1, mon2, wed2, fri2 and so on.

Comment: you said: "I need the default tu throw my the Fri2, as the Fri2 case is the last `valid` case" this is what this does.. if you need something else please edit your question.

Comment: I just edited it. Sorry for this. In my mind was clear because I know exactly what I need

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want to do, you can just move the `default:` label next to the case you want it to match.

Because a `case` or `default` marks the start of the case, and code then continues to the next `break`, stacking several of them right next to each other means they all run the same code.

Note that the `default` doesn't even need to be the last label, and come anywhere in the `switch`.

```
switch($x) {
    case week::Fri1:
        echo "Results 11111"; 
    break;
    case week::Fri2:
    default:
        echo "Results 22222"; 
    break;
}
```

(Note that I've re-formatted the code a bit for clarity. Some people keep `break` statements indented with the code, but I prefer them indented with the `case`/`default`, so the control flow is obvious at a glance.)

Comment: The problem is that I will need to match tuesday, thursday, saturday and sunday too. I don't think that is an option. In my example I have just Fri1 and Fri2, but I will use all those days declared in weeks.